# What syntax highlighter does Chrome use?

Tags: javascript, syntax-highlighting, google-chrome-devtools, chromium

Chrome/Chromium has a syntax highlighter in the inspector that shows black text while scrolling, and highlights after awhile - unlike Firefox Web Developer Toolbar's, which highlights everything and may take a long time. Since the inspector is written in js/html, is there a way to use this technology elsewhere?

Comment: Both answers below are inaccurate. The highligh feature you're talking about is a part of Webkit's source code. The relevant code is mirrored at https://github.com/WebKit/webkit/tree/master/Source/WebCore/inspector/front-end. Good news: The highlight feature is delegated to a Web worker, whose components can easily be tracked. Bad news: The integration in the UI is scattered over some more modules, so it requires more efforts to extract the relevant bits of code.

Answer (score 2):

Chrome's Devtools uses CodeMirror for the sources panel where you can edit code. http://codemirror.net

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can find the source code here:

https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/

[Here are some instructions to get you started.](https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/contributing)

Also, check out [Ace](http://ace.ajax.org/#nav=about) it's very easy to embed and use and does a decent job. Cloud9 uses it.